# Prisma migrate database access denied

Tags: postgresql, prisma

When I try to run the command `npx prisma migrate dev --name init` I get this error message:

```
Error: P1010: User `johndoe` was denied access on the database `mydb.public`
```

I don't remember setting up a user "jhondoe", I just installed postgres desktop on my mac and that's it. I'm new to databases and backend development so I'm not sure if I did setup a user.

Comment: There's no postgres database without a user. But most likely you just didn't configure prisma to use the correct user.

Comment: Can you access the database normally from the application, i.e. when not running a migration?

Comment: yes I'm able to open the postgres sql desktop app, I'm also able to double click each db and the terminal will open. Though a db was not automatically generated for this current project, usually it does when I use prisma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prisma generates a .env file following variables:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://jhondoe:randompassword@localhost:5432/myDB?schema=public"
```

The solution is to just change "jhondoe" to your pc/desktop name. You may also opt to change the password and "myDB" to your preferred database name.